# scroll text in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scroll, uitextview

I have a UITextView: When I do hide the keyboard, I return to the starting point of the text with this code

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    ...
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,1);
    [note scrollRangeToVisible:range];
    return YES; 
}
```

but how can I do to scroll the text when I write, for example, 4 lines? so does not cover the text from the keyboard

thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the contentInset to the height of the keyboard.

Listen for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. Implement something like this:

```
CGFloat keyboardHeight = ... // The userInfo variable contains keyboard info.
[textView setContentInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0)];
```

That will scroll the text view automatically for you.